# each function and .text doesnt work in ie

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, function, text, each

i got a siple code that finds the link's href and if it equals the window location it adds the class to it or for some of div changes the whole text, anyway, hope u'll understand everything from code:

```
$(".menu_link").each(function() {
        if(this.href == window.location) {
            $(this).addClass("selected");
            var text=this.text;
            $('#selected_page').text(text);
        }
    });
```

as u can probably understand from code, i have a multiple links with class menu_link, and if its href is the same with window location it adds the selected class, but the problem is in the text value, the next 2 sentences works fine in all of the browser except for IE. what can be the problem?

Comment: What have you given as the href values? The exact value. I am not sure if your if condition is returning true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my knowledge, the `text` property you're using is not standard (it should be `innerText` or `textContent` depending on the browser).

Try using jQuery's [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method instead:

```
$("#selected_page").text($(this).text());
```